# Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 - Problema haciendo un POST - Strapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router-dom, strapi

tengo un problema haciendo un POST a una API creada en Strapi y estoy usando React vite. el error que sale es que al hacer el submit, en consola me sale POST http://... 400 (Bad Request) y en consola de strapi me sale Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.

El error que arroja Strapi es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto codigos.

Etiqueta Form mandando por un input de tipo submit los datos.

```
<div className="bg-white shadow rounded-md md:w-4/4 mx-auto px-5 py-10 mt-5">
    {errores?.length &&
      errores.map((error, i) => <Error key={i}>{error}</Error>)}

    <Form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
      <FormularioCapacitacion />
      <input
        type="submit"
        className="mt-5 w-full bg-green-800 p-3 uppercase font-bold text-white text-lg"
        value="Registrar Capacitación"
      />
    </Form>
  </div>
```

Funcion Action para validar e enviar informacion al servidor.

```
export async function action({ request }) {
const formData = await request.formData();

  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

  console.log(data);

  //Validación
  const errores = [];
  if (Object.values(data).includes("")) {
    errores.push("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
  }

  //Retornar datos si hay errores
  if (Object.keys(errores).length) {
    return errores;
  }

 await agregarCapacitaciones(data); 

  return redirect("/capacitaciones");
}
```

y por ultimo el codigo sel servicio que envia a la api los datos.

```
export async function agregarCapacitaciones(datos){
console.log(datos);
try {
    const respuesta = await fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_API_STRAPI_CONTENIDOS_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({'data':datos}),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    await respuesta.json()
    
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
}
```

Lo que se envia a la funcion agregarCapacitacion como valor datos es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mi pregunta es: Cuando envías los datos dentro de `agregarCapacitaciones`, ¿La respuesta que obtienes de tu api es un `json`? Lo más probable es que la `respuesta` no sea un json válido y cuando ejecutas la línea `respuesta.json()` tu código explota. Asegúrate por favor de que `respuesta` contenga una respuesta en formato `json` válido. De hecho, elimina la línea `await respuesta.json()` y verifica si se elimina el error, al final no haces nada con la respuesta por lo que veo.

Comment: Ya se lo quite y sigue saliendo el error, lo que llega a la funcion de agregarCapacitaciones como  datos es:
{semana: '1', dia: '3', rango: 'senior', titulo: 'gsgs', descripcion: 'sgsg', …}

Comment: ahi edite la pregunta con mas detalle

Comment: [Revisa esta respuesta de stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380462/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-in-json-at-position-1) Espero que te sirva...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solucion:

En la funcion Action para validar e enviar informacion al servidor, cree una nueva variable donde encerraba la data en un objeto y listo.

```
export async function action({ request }) {
const formData = await request.formData();

const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

const dataFinal = {data}
console.log(dataFinal);
```

y en el fetch del server lo deje solo con Stringify(datos)

```
export async function agregarCapacitaciones(datos){
console.log(datos);
try {
    const respuesta = await 
fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_API_STRAPI_CONTENIDOS_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(datos),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
}
```